# Does Chaquopy support tensorflow 2.2 or 2.3.1?

Tags: android-studio, tensorflow, chaquopy

I see it is installing the version 2.1.0. But couldn't install the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your [Chaquopy version](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/versions.html), the currently available versions are:

- TensorFlow 1.10.1 for Python 3.6
- TensorFlow 2.1.0 for Python 3.8

If you need a newer version, please vote for [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/374), and post a comment explaining why you need it.